# Writing to DSE graph from EMR

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-emr, datastax-enterprise-graph

We are trying to write to write to a DSE graph (cassandra) from EMR and keep getting these errors. My JAR is a shaded jar with the byos dependencies. Any help would be appreciated.

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibraryLinux.getpid()J
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibraryLinux.getpid(Native Method)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibraryLinux.callGetpid(NativeLibraryLinux.java:124)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.NativeLibrary.getProcessID(NativeLibrary.java:429)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen.hash(UUIDGen.java:386)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen.makeNode(UUIDGen.java:367)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen.makeClockSeqAndNode(UUIDGen.java:300)
    at org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen.<clinit>(UUIDGen.java:41)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.sql.vertex.SimpleVertexIdAssigner$.simpleEdgeId(SimpleVertexIdAssigner.scala:19)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$$anonfun$3.apply(DseGraphFrame.scala:417)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$$anonfun$3.apply(DseGraphFrame.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.WholeStageCodegenExec$$anonfun$11$$anon$1.hasNext(WholeStageCodegenExec.scala:619)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.columnar.CachedRDDBuilder$$anonfun$1$$anon$1.hasNext(InMemoryRelation.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIterator(MemoryStore.scala:220)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.memory.MemoryStore.putIteratorAsValues(MemoryStore.scala:298)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1165)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager$$anonfun$doPutIterator$1.apply(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPut(BlockManager.scala:1091)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.doPutIterator(BlockManager.scala:1156)
    at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.getOrElseUpdate(BlockManager.scala:882)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.getOrCompute(RDD.scala:335)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:286)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:52)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:324)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:288)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:90)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:121)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner$$anonfun$10.apply(Executor.scala:402)
    at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryWithSafeFinally(Utils.scala:1360)
    at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:408)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

19/04/26 12:55:49 WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 5.0 (TID 18, ip-10-69-16-79.vpc.internal, executor 1): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.apache.cassandra.utils.UUIDGen
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.sql.vertex.SimpleVertexIdAssigner$.simpleEdgeId(SimpleVertexIdAssigner.scala:19)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$$anonfun$3.apply(DseGraphFrame.scala:417)
    at com.datastax.bdp.graph.spark.graphframe.DseGraphFrame$$anonfun$3.apply(DseGraphFrame.scala:416)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCodegenStage1.processNext(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.BufferedRowIterator.hasNext(BufferedRowIterator.java:43)
```

Comment: what version of BYOS?

Comment: BYOS version -> 6.0.5

Answer (score 0):

Usually such errors happen when temporary directory is mounted with `noexec` attribute that prevents loading of the native library that is used by java driver. Usual workaround to point Java to another location for temporary files with `-Djava.io.tmpdir=...` flag - this location shouldn't be mounted with `noexec` flag.

P.S. Unfortunately I don't know much about EMR

Comment: thanks Alex, unfortunately that didn't work for us.

Comment: Can you try to select another OS version for EMR? What is used right now?

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a JNA issue. Added the JNA dependency as a part of the shaded jar and it worked.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>net.java.dev.jna</groupId>
        <artifactId>jna</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.2</version>
</dependency>
```